# spring mvc and threads and java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc

we are using spring mvc with glassfish/websphere with flex as client.
one of the webservices need to return indication to client and after this continue execution asyncroniously without need to return anything.

we tried to use pure java threads but it didnt work because spring couldnt access web appication context.

then we tried to use threads in "a spring way" (using @async +  )
but spring threw exception:

> 12-11-2013 16:11:44,769 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR
>   com.app.closeQuestionnaire.logic.CloseQuestionnaireBusinessActionsService.handleCRMEventsSending(Line:
>   254)[   userrrr | 30605808 | 2c90908b424ca07a01424ca374c00000 ] -
>   sendCrmEvent request of [questionnaire id:
>   2c90908b424ca07a01424ca374c00000] failed with exception: Error
>   creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.sessionCachedUserMetadata':
>   Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider
>   defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it
>   from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes
>   outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of
>   the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within
>   a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably
>   running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case,
>   use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the
>   current request. (10065)
>   com.app.questionnaire.exceptions.CRMEventException: sendCrmEvent
>   request of [questionnaire id: 2c90908b424ca07a01424ca374c00000] failed
>   with exception: Error creating bean with name
>   'scopedTarget.sessionCachedUserMetadata': Scope 'session' is not
>   active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for
>   this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request
>   found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual
>   web request, or processing a request outside of the originally
>   receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
>   and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside
>   of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.  at
>   com.app.closeQuestionnaire.logic.CloseQuestionnaireBusinessActionsService.handleCRMEventsLogics(CloseQuestionnaireBusinessActionsService.java:780)
>     at
>   com.app.closeQuestionnaire.logic.CloseQuestionnaireBusinessActionsService.handleCRMEventsSending(CloseQuestionnaireBusinessActionsService.java:251)
>     at
>   com.app.closeQuestionnaire.logic.CloseQuestionnaireBusinessActionsService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$729836cc.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
>     at
>   com.app.closeQuestionnaire.logic.CloseQuestionnaireBusinessActionsService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$149b3c4c.handleCRMEventsSending()
>     at
>   com.app.closeQuestionnaire.logic.CloseQuestionnaireBusinessService.postCloseQuestionnaire(CloseQuestionnaireBusinessService.java:111)
>     at
>   com.app.closeQuestionnaire.logic.CloseQuestionnaireBusinessService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2c8c6561.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:617)
>     at
>   com.app.closeQuestionnaire.logic.CloseQuestionnaireBusinessService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1be443b3.postCloseQuestionnaire()
>     at
>   com.app.questionnaire.logic.QuestionnaireBusinessService.postCloseQuestionnaire(QuestionnaireBusinessService.java:327)
>     at
>   com.app.questionnaire.logic.QuestionnaireBusinessService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3ba23fb7.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
>     at
>   com.app.questionnaire.logic.QuestionnaireBusinessService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$95911765.postCloseQuestionnaire()
>     at
>   com.app.questionnaire.util.PostClosePreformerProcess.doClose(PostClosePreformerProcess.java:28)
>     at
>   com.app.questionnaire.util.PostClosePreformerProcess$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3553cc1c.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:80)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>advisor-server</display-name>

    <!-- ========= Context parameters ========= -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <description>Parameter specifying the location of the log4j
            configuration file</description>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>file:${advisorLog4jConfigLocation}</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- ========= Listeners ========= -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <display-name>serviceRefRegistrar</display-name>
        <listener-class>com.app.application.ServiceRefRegistrar
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Loads configuration to make sure we don't crash during runtime in case 
        of parsing errors -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.app.application.ApplicationConfigListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- ========= filters ========= -->

    <filter>
            <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter
            </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.app.general.logging.LoggingFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>AdviserRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.app.commons.application.AdviserRequestFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AdviserRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



</web-app>
```

spring.xml

```
<beans >

    <!-- Context -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.modelity.advisor" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <!-- Activates @Scheduled and @Async annotations for scheduling -->  
    <task:annotation-driven />


</beans>


@Component
public class PostClosePreformerProcess{

    @Autowired
    private QuestionnaireBusinessService questionnaireService;

    public PostClosePreformerProcess() {

    }


    @Async
    public void doClose(String questionnaireId) {
        try {
            questionnaireService.postCloseQuestionnaire(questionnaireId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AdvisorLogger.error(this, "Post Closed Failed", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


    public QuestionnaireBusinessService getQuestionnaireService() {
        return questionnaireService;
    }


    public void setQuestionnaireService(
            QuestionnaireBusinessService questionnaireService) {
        this.questionnaireService = questionnaireService;
    }
}




@Service
public class CloseQuestionnaireBusinessService {

    @Autowired
    private PostClosePreformerProcess postClosePreformerProcess;

    public PreCloseQuestionnaireDto preCloseQuestionnaire(String questionnaireId) {

                postClosePreformerProcess.doClose(questionnaireId);
}
}
```

edit:
indeed we need to stay in session/request scope because async (thread) part need to use beans inside application which defined in scope of session
for example one of beans (that is which the exception complains about):

```
@Component("sessionCachedUserMetadata")
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Lazy(true)
public class UserMetadataSessionCachedService implements UserMetadataBusinessService {
```

Comment: You seem to be using session scope somewhere, but you aren't showing it.

Comment: edited post with an example of usage of one of session beans which is needed